# NDK 25 Did not add optimized level in Build Type Release with CMake

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I'm working on a shared library with CMake. Today I try to build it with NDK 25. when build type is "DEBUG", cmake add -O0 in CXX_FLAGS, and it add "-O2" in "RELWITHDEBINFO" build type. but when I changed it to "RELEASE", no optimize level was set.
I looked into the files that CMake generated. I found this in "CMakeCache.txt":

```
//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=
//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
//Flags used by the CXX compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
//Flags used by the compiler during release builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
//Libraries linked by default with all C++ applications.
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=-latomic -lm
```

I found "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING" is empty, that's why optimize level is not set when buildding "RELEASE".

This is my shell script to run the cmake:

```
NDK_PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105"
rm -rf buildV7
mkdir buildV7
cd buildV7
../../../../CMake/Mac/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake ..
 -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23
 -DANDROID_NDK=$NDK_PATH
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$NDK_PATH/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
make VERBOSE=1
cd ..
```

the final clang command is:

```
Android/sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi23 --sysroot=Android/sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -DBianqueLogger_EXPORTS -I/Users/TestProj/build/android/dynamicLib/../../../src -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -DNDEBUG  -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/BianqueLogger.dir/Users/TestProj/src/utils/head.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/BianqueLogger.dir/Users/TestProj/src/utils/head.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/BianqueLogger.dir/Users/TestProj/src/utils/head.cpp.o -c /Users/TestProj/src/utils/head.cpp
```

Is This NDK's BUG? Or -O3 is no longer needed in NDK25 and it's clang toolchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Release" - there is no such config by default in NDK since r23. The default configs are: "Debug", "MinSizeRel" and "RelWithDebInfo". Use one of these three.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1740. Will be fixed in r25b.

But typically you don't want to use `Release` for Android, you want to use `RelWithDebInfo` or `MinSizeRel` (it's really unfortunate that cmake doesn't have a `MinSizeRelWithDebInfo`). Your packaging tools should be stripping any libraries before packing them into an APK, so there is no reason to avoid compiling debug info. All that does is make it so you can't debug.